# My Do-While loop doesn't seem to loop?

Tags: c, loops, do-while

Please help, I cant seem to get the do-while loop to loop when I ask the user to input continue using scanf and printf. Could it be the wipe_buffer? I can't seem to get it right on this and I just need to finish the loop and that should be mostly functional. New to coding and this website please not too harsh. please and thanks.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
void wipe_buffer(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{
    char play1;
    char play2;
    char cont;

    do{
        printf("Player one pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors\n");
        scanf(" %c", &play1);
        wipe_buffer();
        printf("Player two pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors\n");
        scanf(" %c", &play2);
        wipe_buffer();

        switch(play1)
        {
            case 'r':
                 if(play2 == 'p' || play2 == 'P')
            {
                printf("Paper Covers Rock\n");
                printf("Player two wins\n");
            }
                if(play2 == 's' || play2 == 'S')
                {
                    printf("Rock Breaks Scissors\n");
                    printf("Player one wins\n");
                }
                if(play2 == 'r' || play2 == 'R')
                {
                    printf("Draw, Nobody wins\n");
                }
            break;
            case 'R':
                if(play2 == 'p' || play2 == 'P')
            {
                printf("Paper Covers Rock\n");
                printf("Player two wins\n");
            }
                if(play2 == 's' || play2 == 'S')
                {
                    printf("Rock Breaks Scissors\n");
                    printf("Player one wins\n");
                }
                if(play2 == 'r' || play2 == 'R')
                {
                    printf("Draw, Nobody wins\n");
                }
            break;
            case 'P':
                 if(play2 == 'p' || play2 == 'P')
            {
                printf("Draw, Nobody wins\n");
            }
                if(play2 == 's' || play2 == 'S')
                {
                    printf("Scissors cuts Paper\n");
                    printf("Player two wins\n");
                }
                if(play2 == 'r' || play2 == 'R')
                {
                    printf("Paper covers rock\n");
                }
            break;
            case 'p':
                 if(play2 == 'p' || play2 == 'P')
            {
                printf("Draw, Nobody wins\n");
            }
                if(play2 == 's' || play2 == 'S')
                {
                    printf("Scissors cuts Paper\n");
                    printf("Player two wins\n");
                }
                if(play2 == 'r' || play2 == 'R')
                {
                    printf("Paper covers rock\n");
                }
            break;
            case 's':
                 if(play2 == 'p' || play2 == 'P')
            {
                printf("Scissors Cuts Paper\n");
                printf("Player one wins\n");
            }
                if(play2 == 's' || play2 == 'S')
                {
                    printf("Draw, Nobody wins\n");
                }
                if(play2 == 'r' || play2 == 'R')
                {
                    printf("Rock breaks Scissors\n");
                    printf("Player two wins\n");
                }
            break;
            case 'S':
                 if(play2 == 'p' || play2 == 'P')
            {
                printf("Scissors Cuts Paper\n");
                printf("Player one wins\n");
            }
                if(play2 == 's' || play2 == 'S')
                {
                    printf("Draw, Nobody wins\n");
                }
                if(play2 == 'r' || play2 == 'R')
                {
                    printf("Rock breaks Scissors\n");
                    printf("Player two wins\n");
                }
            break;
        }
    printf("Do you wish to continue?\n");
    scanf(" &c", &cont);
    wipe_buffer();
    }while(cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');
}
void wipe_buffer(void)
{
    char t;
    scanf("%c", &t);
    while(t != '\n' )
    {
        scanf("%c", &t);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yet another RPS question.

Comment: I read `scanf(" &c", &cont);` before the end of your do-while loop. I suspect you must change that `&` inside the string by a `%`. It's been a while since I did C.

Comment: RPS question? lol sorry im noob if you could point me in the right direction that would be nice, and that did it lol thanks naitoon! I just couldn't find my mistake.

Comment: when you call `wipe_buffer` t is equal to `\n` so the loop isn't even considered just put a `getchar()` after each `scanf` and you'll be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this section:

```
    printf("Do you wish to continue?\n");
scanf(" &c", &cont);
```

`"&c"` should be `"%c"`

Note that when I compiled this with gcc, I got a warning that basically addressed this exact problem, so make sure to read your warnings.

Comment: that's odd i use codeblocks and it just ran through without error? I could be looking at the wrong place

Comment: I also ran it with codeblocks. See if -Wall is checked in the build options - it was for me by default.

Answer (score 2):

In here:

```
printf("Do you wish to continue?\n");
    scanf(" &c", &cont);
    wipe_buffer();
    }while(cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');
```

there should be:

```
scanf(" %c", &cont);
```

Compile with `-Wall -pedantic` options next time you face some problem(if you use gcc).
It shows nicely where the problem lies, and if not - it narrows it down a little.

That's what it shows in your case:

```
test2.c:117:5: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
test2.c:120:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

so it's also a nice reminder that your `main()` function has to `return` some value.

Another suggestion is to rad through this link:http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-60.html
and follow to The Steps page.
To make it short - there's some information on how time and space consuming is reading one char from `stdin` with `scanf` in comparison to `getchar`.
Consider applying this suggestion in your code.

Answer (score 0):

So, a really quick way to see what's going on is to drop a debugging `printf` statement right before the loop

```
    scanf(" &c", &cont);
    wipe_buffer();
    printf("Debug: [%c]\n", cont);
    }while(cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');
```

Then look for the `printf` when the program runs.

I think what is going on is that each `scanf` is looking for a Enter keystroke before processing, so `wipe_buffer` is going to request a lot of Enter keystrokes before continuing. Try running the program without the `wipe_buffer` and you'll still need to press Enter before it continues.